# Can't select chechbox with v-model in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vue-component

I have a checkbox as a feature filter for a real estate agency site.

From the database comes the list of categories with their respective characteristics:

```
public function get_categories(Request $request)
{

    $categories = Category::with('features')->get();

    return response()->json([
        'validation' => true,
        'categories' => $categories
    ]);

}
```

In the Vue template, I have an accordion with UIKit.

I have one accordion header per category that I walk through using a v-for

Then inside the body of the accordion I have the checkboxes that correspond to the characteristics that belong to that category

```
<li 
    v-for="category in categories" 
    :key="category.id">
    
    <a 
        href="#" 
        class="uk-accordion-title">
        {{ category.name }}
    </a>

    <div class="uk-accordion-content">
        
        <div uk-grid>
            
            <div 
                class="uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small"
                v-for="feature in category.features"
                :key="feature.id">
                
                <label>
                    
                    <input 
                        :id="'feature_' + feature.id"
                        class="uk-checkbox"
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="features" 
                        :value="feature.id"
                        v-model="features"
                        @change="filterUpdate"> <!-- ID hacer que este sea venga de la BD -->
                    
                        &nbsp; {{ feature.name }}

                </label>

            </div>

        </div>
        
    </div>

</li>
```

To load the categories of course I have a method that is responsible for making the request when creating the component

```
layoutLoadCategories() {

    axios.get('api/layout/get/categories').then( res => {

        this.categories = res.data.categories;

    });

},
```

The problem is that when I try to click on a checkbox, nothing happens. Not selected
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you are using v-model you no need to use :value and moreover since its a checkbox input you v-model variable should hold only boolean value (ie) either true or false

```
  <input 
    :id="'feature_' + feature.id"
    class="uk-checkbox"
    type="checkbox"
    name="features" 
    v-model="features" // here I guess features is an object or array...so assign a variable that is of type Boolean
    @change="filterUpdate">
```

Comment: Still not working.

Even if you remove all data bindings, the checkboxes don't work.

Comment: then pls check if you have disabled all the inputs through any other means

Answer (score 0):

I have already worked out, in the form tag I had @ click.prevent

I have removed the .prevent and it already works

Before:

```
<form id="filter_form" action="/property-browser" method="get" @click.prevent="filterUpdate">
```

After:

```
<form id="filter_form" action="/property-browser" method="get" @click="filterUpdate">
```